# AMD Drivers for Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, gpu

So I've recently upgraded from Windows 10 to Ubuntu V. 20.10, I'm kinda confused because things are new (terminals and crap) So I know the latest AMD Drivers are for the version 20.04 but I really don't want to downgrade (I've heard it's a pain in the butt) and don't want to lose all my stuff. Also, If I do install my drivers, would it improve my game?

While I'm at it, Steam Games (primarily CS:GO) runs quite crappy on my PC, I've gotten like 100-110 fps on Windows 10 but now I can't even get into a match. I know it seems a lot but I'd really appreciate it if y'all could point me to a fix or something. My GPU's the R9 290 by the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Radeon 200-series cards are just one generation too old to out-of-the-box use the modern Linux `AMDGPU` driver. By default, Ubuntu would have you using the older 'radeon' driver. I used to have a R290X, so I know this pain :)

However, you can change some Linux kernel settings via GRUB configuration to enable experimental support for 200-series cards in `AMDGPU`, if you're comfortable with doing that. Ubuntu kernels already have the relevant features enabled to support this.

Right now from your running system, if you run the terminal command `lsmod | grep radeon`, you should see a 'radeon' in the list. Likewise, if you run the command `lsmod | grep amdgpu`, nothing should appear. `lsmod` shows you the running kernel modules (drivers) on the system. We'll come back to this later.

To do so, you'll need to do 2 steps:

**1) Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file**

From the terminal, run:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

This will bring up a simple terminal text editor. Use the arrow keys to navigate.

Go to the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" and append "radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 modprobe.blacklist=radeon", so it looks like this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 modprobe.blacklist=radeon"`

Press `CTRL+X` to save/exit, then press `Y` at the "Save?" prompt, and finally `ENTER` to save at the same file name. Nano should then return you to the terminal.

**2) Regenerate GRUB config**

Finally, we just need to recreate your GRUB config with:

`sudo update-grub`

That's it. Reboot, and you should be using the `AMDGPU` driver.

From your rebooted system, now if you run the terminal command `lsmod | grep radeon`, 'radeon' should NOT appear in the list. Likewise, if you run the command `lsmod | grep amdgpu`, now it should appear. That's how you can confirm you are using the modern `AMDGPU` driver.

Hope this helps!

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_Rx_200_series#Radeon_Feature_Matrix
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#Enable_Southern_Islands_(SI)_and_Sea_Islands_(CIK)_support

Comment: Hey, looks like that did it although the performance on CS:GO (somehow it's only CS:GO cause I get good/decent frames on Minecraft and Payday 2) I don't know if it's an issue within Valve or Linux but meh. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that worked. I do remember doing this with my R9 290X, and yes, it wasn't great in terms of performance haha, so it's not just you. `AMDGPU` is still "experimential" with these 1st Generation GCN cards and isn't optimized very well, but it does work better than the older `radeon` driver, so it's... something. I did end up having to go back to dual-booting Windows for serious gaming when I still had the 290X.